# Add language detection column in power bi

Tags: python, powerbi

I use power bi extensively, I want to add language detection column based on the tweet which we receive in different languages in my 'Message' field. 
I try this python script, but not working:

```
  **# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
    # - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-
import pandas as pd
 from textblob import TextBlob
 wiki=TextBlob()
 dataset['Jamal'] = dataset['Message'].apply(lambda x: wiki.detect_language(x).['compound'])
```

Comment: not working you mean  there are some errors or not detecting language?

Comment: I am receiving this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 17, in <module>
    wiki=TextBlob()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'